# Filtering instances by IAM role in boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Is there a way to filter instances by IAM role?
Basically I want a script that terminates all the instances that I've launched, but doesn't touch instances launched with other IAM roles.

Comment: you should tag them instead and use that.  IAM roles might not be expected to be used in this way and if anyone else (or you accidentally) tries to use the IAM role for some similar purpose, then you're SOL when you accidentally terminate an instance that shouldn't be terminated because you did something unexpected.  Tags are meant to be used in this way.

Comment: Agree that filtering on instance profile is not ideal, but here's how you could do this with the awscli (and you can work out the equivalent with boto3): aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].{id:InstanceId, role:IamInstanceProfile.Arn}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1:**

If it is just a one-time activity, you can consider using aws-cli itself.

Use the below aws-cli command to list all instances with a particular IAM Role.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[?IamInstanceProfile.Arn==`<Enter you Instance Profile ARN here>`].{InstanceId: InstanceId}' --output text
```

Replace `<Enter you Instance Profile ARN here>` with the *Instance Profile Arn*.

**NOTE:**
You must enter the *`Instance Profile Arn`* and **NOT** the *`Role ARN`*.

*Instance Profile Arn* will be of the form:

> arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:instance-profile/Profile-ASDNSDLKJ

You can then pass the list of `Instance-id's` returned above to the `terminate-instance` cli command. The *instance-ids* must be separated by spaces.

`aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids i-1234567890abcdef0 i-1234567890jkefpq1`

**Method 2:**

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-east-1')
response = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'iam-instance-profile.arn',
            'Values': [
                'arn:aws:iam::1234567890:instance-profile/MyProfile-ASDNSDLKJ',
            ]
        },
    ]
)
terminate_instance_list = []
for resp in response['Reservations']:
  for inst in resp['Instances']:
    #print inst['InstanceId']
    terminate_instance_list.append(inst['InstanceId'])


#print(terminate_instance_list)
if terminate_instance_list:
    response = client.terminate_instances(
        InstanceIds=terminate_instance_list
    )
    print(response)
```